# Blank screen when updating data in php table

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have been working on a project and i am at the final stages of the project. My problem is whenever i try to update data in my database table into returns a blank screen with no error messages. Please find the php script and html form (the form responsible for updating the database table) below, i have divided it into about four sections:

Thanks in advance

**Update Form:**

```
<a name="inventoryEditForm" id="inventoryEditForm"></a>
<h3>&darr;Add New Question Form&darr;</h3>  
<form action="inventory_edit.php" enctype="multipart/from-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="7">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="80%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question</td>
            <td><textarea rows="" name="question" cols=""><?php echo $question; ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Venue</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="venue" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $venue; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="questiondate" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Question">
    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear Form">
</form>
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php

//Error reporting due to long script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php

error_reporting(E_PARSE);
//Update question table
If (isset($_POST['question'])) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['thisID']);
    $question = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['question']);
    $venue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['venue']);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['questiondate']);
    //Update question in the table
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE DebateQuestion SET question='$question',venue='$venue',date='$date' WHERE qQuestionNo='$id'LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    header("location: inventory.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<?php

error_reporting(E_PARSE);
//Gather this questions full information and insert automatically into the edit form
if (isset($_GET['qid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['qid'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM DebateQuestion WHERE qQuestionNo='$targetID'LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $questionCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

    if ($questionCount > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row["qQuestionNo"];
            $question = $row["qQuestion"];
            $venue = $row["qDebateVenue"];
            $date = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["qDate"]));
        }
    } else {
        echo "Oops, no questions like that exists. Check <a href='inventory.php'>inventory</a>again";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: At a glance, it looks like your code ought to parse correctly, but keep in mind that parse errors will not be reported if your php.ini (or .htaccess) isn't configured to do so.  Simply setting error reporting behavior in your code will not work if there are parsing errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your update query you have the data column without using ` back ticks , date is also a mysql's function try to wrap up your column names with back ticks if you are not sure whether they conflict with mysql's reserved keywords

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE DebateQuestion SET 
`question`='$question',`venue`='$venue',`date`='$date' 
 WHERE qQuestionNo='$id'LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: date is not a reserved word in mysql,still good to use backticks.

Comment: @dianuj I tried adding the back ticks but the white screen still pops up. I feel like the problem is from my UPDATE statement

Comment: Also am not sure all data are being passed from the form to the database table

Comment: @user1889672 First check it is coming in if check or not by using die(), and the echo your query `"UPDATE DebateQuestion SET 
question='$question',venue='$venue',date='$date' 
 WHERE qQuestionNo='$id'LIMIT 1` and run directly in phpmyadmin to see if there is any errors

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM DebateQuestion WHERE qQuestionNo='$targetID'LIMIT 1"
```

Here is qQuestionNo column a string type?if not remove quotes around `$targetID`.

Comment: Thanks Guys

The problem as i suspected was from the form. 

The form action was initially sent to the same page (inventory_edit.php), but it is meant to be sent to a different page from which the question id is being passed (i.e. inventory.php)

I made that change and it works apparently

Answer (score 0):

Note : I have not tested the code - just read it on screen.

I've never seen an IF statement capitalized before :

```
If (isset($_POST['question'])) {
```

I'd guess this makes a difference however.

There's lots of other weird things going on in your files, but none that should give you white screen. Try lowercase 'I' in your if statement first.

ALSO - re: the UPDATE statement, you are missing a space between the $id and the LIMIT :

```
**qQuestionNo='$id'LIMIT 1**
```

Comment: Thanks Guys

The problem as i suspected was from the form. 

The form action was initially sent to the same page (inventory_edit.php), but it is meant to be sent to a different page from which the question id is being passed (i.e. inventory.php)

I made that change and it works apparently